# Create new node from text inside paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site with a lot of paragraphs. Some of them have text and image:

```
<p>first paragraph</p>
<p>second paragraph</p>
<p>third paragraph</p>
<p>fourth paragraph<img alt="alt" src="src"/></p>
<p>fifth paragraph</p>
```

I would like to have numbered paragraphs with the `<img>` tags wrapped in new paragraphs:

```
<p id="1">first paragraph</p>
<p id="2">second paragraph</p>
<p id="3">third paragraph</p>
<p id="4">fourth paragraph</p>
<p id="5"><img alt="alt" src="src"/></p>
<p id="6">fifth paragraph</p>
```

Please note that if the text inside paragraph 4 is after the image, then the final situation should be:

```
<p id="1">first paragraph</p>
<p id="2">second paragraph</p>
<p id="3">third paragraph</p>
<p id="4"><img alt="alt" src="src"/></p>
<p id="5">fourth paragraph</p>
<p id="6">fifth paragraph</p>
```

Now I have only this code, but it doesn't add the image into a separate paragraph:

```
elem.find('p').each(function () {
    id++;
    $(this).attr('id', 'id_' + id);
});
```

Comment: There is no reason to enumerate elements with ids - btw, numerical-only ids are invalid.

Comment: @Bergi: not in HTML5 they're not.

Answer (score 3):

One approach:

```
$('p').each(
    function(i){
        while(this.childNodes.length > 1) {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.appendChild(this.childNodes[1]);
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(p,this.nextSibling);
        }
    });

$('p').attr('data-index',function(i) { return i; });​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gq36e/).

I've amended the first chunk of code in order to preserve the order of the childNodes (which is flawed in [this example using the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gq36e/2/) (check out the second `textNode` following the `img`, it's in the wrong place):

```
$('p').each(
    function(i){
        while(this.childNodes.length > 1) {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.appendChild(this.lastChild);
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(p,this.nextSibling);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gq36e/1/).

Comment: @Andreas: thank you! Though I'm a little disappointed that I can't combine the two chains (I know *why* I can't, but...darn, it just looks messy that way!).

Comment: I don't understant where you check if the <img> is before or after the text

Comment: I don't, I just assumed that the first child-node (whatever it is) should remain in the `this` (the current) element, and whatever follows (whether a `textNode` or an `img` (or anything else)) should be appended to a new `p` element and inserted following the current element.

Comment: Smart. I didn't know about the <textnode>. Looks like you've just got a fan! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAJzT/2/)

```
$('p').each(function(index, p) {
    p.find('img').each(function() {
        if (p.text() != '') {
            var newParagraph = $('<p></p>');
            var html = p.html();
            newParagraph.append($(this));

            if (html.substring(0,1) != '<') {
                p.after(newParagraph);
            }
            else {
                p.before(newParagraph);
            }

        }         
    });
});

$('p').each(function(i) {
   $(this).attr('id', i);
});
```

Comment: You can avoid the `var p = $(this);` with `each()`: `each(function(index, element) { // element === this, $(el) === $(this) });`

Comment: Yeah' I've just seen your answer. You sir are a javascript ninja! +1